# Red pulsing status bar on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, uistatusbar

I was wondering what I would need to be able to use the red pulsing status bar with the app name, when the application goes to background-mode. I've seen several apps using this functionality, but I can't really find any information about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a "return to app" status bar when app goes to the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320372/how-to-create-a-return-to-app-status-bar-when-app-goes-to-the-background)

Answer (score 3):

If you have an active `AudioQueue` recording session, you will get the red status bar automatically.